# whats the problem with this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please redit thisquery if there are any problemin that :

```
SELECT [travel], [service], [travelid], [fro_m], [t_o], [dep], [arr], [booking_closed],
[discount], [faresleeper], [rating], [seats], [s_no], 
[fare] = 
CASE 
  WHEN @date >= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1from,101) as datetime
    AND @date >= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1to,101) as datetime 
  THEN s1rate 
  ELSE fare 
END 
FROM a1_volvo WHERE  ( fro_m = @fro_m ) AND ( t_o = @t_o )
```

Comment: No problem at all.  :-) A problem means you have an expected behavior, and you are not getting what you expect. So, what is the expected behavior, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem with the query? Do you get an error? Is something unexpected happening? Does your SQL server catch on fire? With only the query, you're making this question hard to answer.

Comment: what problem/error do you have with the query ?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what problem you are having with this query. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [travel], [service], [travelid], [fro_m], [t_o], [dep], [arr], [booking_closed],
[discount], [faresleeper], [rating], [seats], [s_no], 
[fare] = 
CASE 
  WHEN @date >= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1from,101) as datetime)
    AND @date >= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1to,101) as datetime )
  THEN s1rate 
  ELSE fare 
END 
FROM a1_volvo WHERE  ( fro_m = @fro_m ) AND ( t_o = @t_o )
```

Answer (score 1):

In the *WHEN* statement, should'nt it be

WHEN @date **>=** Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1from,101) as datetime

AND @date **<=** Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1to,101) as datetime

with one **greater equal** and one **lesser equal** if it is a range check?

Answer (score 1):

Check your cast it should be **cast(column as datatype)** and also consider the **greater than equal to ">=" and lesser than equal to "<="** as what il_guru have said. :)
Check this out...

```
SELECT [travel], [service], [travelid], [fro_m], [t_o], [dep], [arr],
  [booking_closed], [discount], [faresleeper], [rating], [seats], [s_no],      
  [fare] = CASE WHEN @date >= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1from,101) as datetime)
       AND @date <= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1to,101) as datetime)
       THEN s1rate ELSE fare END  
FROM a1_volvo  

-- use this where clause if fro_m and t_o are not datetime
WHERE (fro_m = @fro_m ) AND ( t_o = @t_o )

-- else use this where clause if fro_m and t_o have datetime of datatypes
WHERE ( Cast(Convert(varchar(20),fro_m,101) as datetime) = @fro_m ) 
AND (  Cast(Convert(varchar(20),t_o,101) as datetime) = @t_o )
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `[fare] =` and try again.